# Boolean flags in Presenters to control flow of execution

Tags: design, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

I can see people use `boolean` flags, especially in `Controllers` / `Presenters`, to control the flow of execution. For example,

```
public void onButtonClicked() {
    hasButtonClicked=true
    // code here
}
```

Then later, in an unrelated method, but still of the same `Presenter` this flag is utilized something along the lines:

```
public void onSomeOtherActionHappened() {
    if (hasButtonClicked) {
    // execute this
    } else {
    // execute that
    }

}
```

Not only does make it harder to unit test it, it's also hard to follow the intention of the flag and when it changes its state.

It just smells to me. I normally replace such flags with `Object`s which really facilitates unit testing. And yet, I'm still wondering, is there anything humanity already thought about, would it be possible to avoid using such flags to represent a state, how to approach it differently and how to explain why it smells. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing wrong with booleans. There is nothing wrong with control flow. That's just computer programming for you. There are cases where the repeated use of a conditional is better replaced by polymorphism, but that is not the norm.

A conditional in a method is not at all problematic, provided that the overall cyclomatic complexity is still low enough to be easily testable. If the conditional is very large and the two branches are quite different and have no clear parallels or interactions, they are better extracted into a private helper methods which you can test separately (yes, please test your private methods). However, introducing separate objects and handling the conditional via polymorphism is in the most cases far less obvious, and non-obvious code is dangerous code. Your control flow is suddenly implicit, and spread over multiple classes. This makes large “object-oriented” systems extremely difficult to read or debug, for a marginal increase of testability – the spaghetti code of our times.

So unless you have a good reason to refactor that conditional, leave it there.

Comment: Excellent point about maintainability.  As an old-time coder (yes, I remember punch-cards).  I've seen OO coding used as an excuse to abandon structured coding and implicit coding is a nightmare to maintain.